# Django administration

Tags: django, postgresql

I create superuser Django administration gives me an error when trying to login (Please enter the correct username and password for a staff account. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.) It can be said that I checked almost every option, but still I could not login to Django administration. How can I solve this problem?

1.Delete database
2.I delete migrations
AND etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/install/) first on the Django website
You also have a [tuto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/intro/tutorial01/).
Good luck